# наследование java, возврат значений

Tags: java, наследование

Изучаю java, по книге head first java, там дан пример, он должен выводить данную программу в виде:

a bite?
breath fire
arrrgh

У меня возникли некоторые вопросы, закомментировал в программе. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
public class MonsterTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monster[] ma = new Monster[3];
        ma[0] = new Vampire();
        ma[1] = new Dragon();
        ma[2] = new Monster();

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            ma[x].frighten(x);
        }
    }
}

class Monster {

    boolean frighten(int d) {  // как используется данный аргумент int d? он просто нужен для считывания действия frighten(x)   ?
        System.out.println("arrrgh");
        return true;  // какая разница возвращать false или true, если все равно выполняется программа. Я так понимаю просто выполняется вывод на экран и метод завершается,а true или false без разницы??
    }
}

class Vampire extends Monster {

    boolean frighten (int x) {   //чтобы было если бы здесь был не int x, а byte x, тогда код компилируется,но не перенаследуется от класса Monster, обязательно должно быть совпадение int - int?
        System.out.println("a bite?");
        return true;
    }
}

class Dragon extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(int degree) {
        System.out.println("breath fire");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
boolean frighten(int d) {  // как используется данный аргумент int d? он просто нужен для считывания действия frighten(x)   ?
     System.out.println("arrrgh");
    return true;  // какая разница возвращать false или true, если все равно выполняется программа. Я так понимаю просто выполняется вывод на экран и метод завершается,а true или false без разницы??
}
```

`int d` в данном примере никак не используется, как и возвращаемое значение.
Вполне можно было написать `void frighten()`, тогда `return` не нужен и вызов будет без параметра.

```
boolean frighten (int x) {   //чтобы было если бы здесь был не int x, а byte x, тогда код компилируется,но не перенаследуется от класса Monster, обязательно должно быть совпадение int - int?
    System.out.println("a bite?");
    return true;
}
```

Если написать `byte x`, то переопределения метода не будет, и в классе наследнике будут доступны две версии метода, в зависимости от передаваемого параметра.
Когда же параметры совпадают(int - int) метод переопределяется, но метод родителя по прежнему доступен через `super.frighten(параметр);`

Comment: Если написать boolean frighten (byte x) то правильно я понял наследуется метод от предка и создается свой метод frighten (byte x). Но он в данной программе не запустится, так как вызывается только frighten(int x), а не frighten(byte x)?

Comment: Да, именно так.